# Delete query in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I can retrieve data easily from this, but while I tried from delete it deletes all the data of my table, what's going wrong in this?

```
$db = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$sel = new Sql($db);
$s=$sel->delete('milestone','goal_id='.$edit_id);
echo $s->getSqlString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the id.

Try this:-

```
<?php

        $db = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $sql = new Sql( $db );
        $delete = $sql->delete('milestone')->where("goal_id = $edit_id");
       //see the deleted entry    
        $deleteString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($delete);
        echo $deleteString;
?>
```

Comment: better `$delete = $sql->delete('milestone'); $delete->where->equalTo('goal_id', $edit_id);` this way, you use prepared statements.